# Would like to create an array with number of matches for specific regexs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Would like to create an array with number of matches for specific regexs:
So if january was found 5 times , feb 3 the table would be:
monthFound=[5,3......]

```
function findMonth(){
        var fpath='log.txt';
        var monthFound=[]
              fs.readFileSync(fpath).toString().split('\n').forEach(function(line) 
              {
                      var regExpressions1=[/-jan-/,/-feb-/,/-mar-/,/-apr-/,/-may-/,/-jun-/,/-jul-/,/-aug/,/-sep-/,/-oct-/,/-nov/,/-dec-/];

                      for (var i = 0; i<regExpressions1.length;i++) 
                      {
                        var idx = line.match(regExpressions1[i]);
                        if (idx !== null) {
                            y++;                             
                          }    
                       }
            }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
function findMonth(){
  var fpath='log.txt';
  var monthFound=[]
  fs.readFileSync(fpath).toString().split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
    var regExpressions1=["-jan-","-feb-","-mar-","-apr-","-may-","-jun-","-jul-","-aug-","-sep-","-oct-","-nov-","-dec-"];

    for (var i = 0; i<regExpressions1.length;i++) {
      var idx = line.match(new RegExp(Expressions1[i]));
      monthFound[i] === idx.length                
    }
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return an array with each month match count:

```
fs.readFileSync(fpath).toString().split('\n').reduce((count, str) => {
    ['-jan-','-feb-','-mar-','-apr-','-may-','-jun-','-jul-','-aug-','-sep-','-oct-','-nov-','-dec-'].forEach((month, idx) => {
        const match = (str.match(new RegExp(month, 'g')) || []).length;
        if (count[idx]) {
            count[idx] += match;
        } else {
            count[idx] = match;
        }
    });
    return count;
}, []);
```

Comment: Wow ,thank you ,  works as a charm, the only problem I have now is how to put this returned value to my array monthFound=[]

Comment: monthFound = fs.readFileSync(fpath).toString().split('\n').reduce(.....

Comment: just want to say thank you, spent a half day trying and you ust gave it to me. Owe you a beer.